# Escape characters with ag.vim

Tags: vim

In normal mode I want `K` to search for the word under the cursor with [ag.vim](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim). In visual mode I want `K` to search for the visual selection. This is what I have so far:

```
nnoremap <silent> K :Ag <C-R><C-W><CR>:copen<CR>
vnoremap <silent> K y:Ag <C-R>"<CR>:copen<CR>
```

However, it does not work with characters that needs to be escaped. (As far as I understand that is characters like `%`, `#`, `/`, etc)

If I select the following text `<C-R>"<CR>:copen<CR>` in visual mode and hit `K` an error occurs:

```
Error detected while processing function ag#Ag
```

From [ag.vim](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim)'s homepage:

> Some characters have special meaning, and need to be escaped your
>   search pattern. For instance, '#'. You have to escape it like this :Ag
>   '\\\#define foo' to search for #define foo.

So basically I need to escape the output + escape `#` with `\\\#` (the gotcha above) before it is passed to `Ag`.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape those chars.
Something like this should work (this is untested):

```
:xnoremap  K y:<c-u>Ag <C-R>=shellescape(expand(@"),1)<CR>:copen<CR>
:nnoremap  K :<c-u>Ag <c-r>=shellescape(expand("<cword>"),1)<cr>:copen<cr>
```

Note, I used `xnoremap` instead of vnoremap, so that the mapping does not interfere with select mode. 
Note also, depending on what you want, you might want to use `<cWORD>` instead of `<cword>` (see the help at `:h <cword>`)

Comment: I think you have to replace `shellescape()` with `escape()`.

Comment: I am not sure, but since the input will probably fed to the shell, it should be shellescape()

Comment: `shellescape('#Foo')` will turn `#Foo` into `'#Foo'` but `escape('#Foo', '#')` will turn it into `\#Foo`. Using both, `shellescape(escape('#Foo', '#'))`, seems to do what the OP is asking.

Comment: That's what the second argument in shellescape() is for ;)

Comment: I had to add an additional <CR> after the `shellescape`. But even with that, searching for something like: `nnoremap <silent> K :<C-U>Ag -Q <C-R>=shellescape(escape(expand("<cword>"), '#'), 1)<CR><CR>` results in: `No alternate file name to substitute for '#': ag --column 'nnoremap <silent> K :<C-U>Ag -Q <C-R>=shellescape(escape(expand("nnoremap"), '\''#'\''), 1)<CR><CR>'`. Looks like it expands <cword> in the search (I had my cursor over the word `nnoremap` in this case). I am experimenting with the `-Q` flag in `ag`. But it already seems very complicated for such a simple operation.

Comment: @agronemann: It's a bit easier to debug with echo: `nnoremap K :echo <C-R>=shellescape(escape(expand("<cWORD>"), '#'), 1)<CR><CR>` If I put that on `ag#Ag`, I get `ag\\#Ag`. If I remove the escape() call, I get `ag\#Ag`. I think the second is what you want (Christian Brabandt's original answer).

Comment: The solution provided in this answer solves most cases. But there are still some edge cases where it doesn't work though.